# Type NSError? does not conform to protocol '_RawOptionSetType'

Tags: swift, nserror

I have the following statement:

```
func sessionStateChanged(session:FBSession, state:FBSessionState, error:NSError?) {
        // If the session was opened successfully
        if error == nil && state == FBSessionStateOpen {
            println("Session opened");
        }
}
```

which has the following error on the line of the if-statement:

```
Type NSError? does not conform to protocol '_RawOptionSetType'
```

However if I remove the second condition, so the code reads:

```
if error == nil {
    println("Session opened");
}
```

There is no error. This leads me to believe tat the NSError? type is not the issue and that it has something to do with the multiple conditions.

Comment: @user2864740 updated with method signature

Comment: @Mundi you're right... and I should have done that to begin with. That helped me solve the issue.

Comment: OK, I will make an answer you can accept. Please comment on the answer to explain the actual code correction to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get clearer error messages might be to start a new `if` statement inside the first rather than combining with `&&` .

Comment: I had to compare `state.value == FBSessionStateOpen.value`. Unfortunately, the error xcode was providing me was not relevant to the true issue.